# Sqlite3.c uses version 3.7.17 and adb shell sqlite3 --version says 3.7.4. Will it create any issue to my App

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting  unable to open database exception. I am getting this exception  only after long run when I am touching my App.

So my Questions is : Will version difference is reason for this crash? 
How to upgrade adb shell sqlite3 --version to  sqlite3 version 3.7.17

I am using ICS Os.

Any other Solution  for my problem will be helpful

**This is my Code  on java layer**

```
 public static DatabaseHandler getInstance(Context context) {

    if (oDatabaseHandler == null) 
    {
        oDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return oDatabaseHandler;
   }


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
     String path =   context.getDatabasePath(DatabaseHandler.DATABASE_NAME).toString();  
}
```

// Creating Tables

```
     @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
     {

    String CREATE_TABLE_DIAGNOSIS        = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  " + TABLE_Diagnosistble + "("+KEY_DiagID+ " TEXT PRIMARY KEY ," +KEY_PName+ " TEXT ," +KEY_HospitalNumber+ " TEXT ," +KEY_Gender+ " TEXT ," + KEY_Pacemaker+ " TEXT ," +KEY_DiagType+ " TEXT , " +KEY_Age+ " TEXT ," + KEY_D_DeviceID+ " TEXT ," +KEY_D_DiagStrtTime+ " TEXT ," +KEY_D_DiagEndTime+ " TEXT ," +KEY_D_DiagStatus+ " TEXT ," +KEY_D_ReportStatus+ " TEXT , " +KEY_D_UploadStatus+ " TEXT , " +KEY_D_ChestLead1+ " TEXT ," +KEY_D_ChestLead2+ " TEXT " + ");"; 
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DIAGNOSIS);

    String CREATE_TABLE_PASTEVENTS       = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  " + TABLE_Pasteventstble + "("+KEY_SerNo+ " INTEGER ," +KEY_Trans_ID+ " TEXT ," +KEY_PEDiagID+ " TEXT ," +KEY_AlarmID+ " INTEGER ," +KEY_PktCounter+ " INTEGER  , "+KEY_EventNo+" INTEGER ," +KEY_StartTime+ " TEXT ," +KEY_EndTime+ " TEXT , " + KEY_ECG_UploadStatus+ " TEXT , " + KEY_ECGMode+ " INTEGER " + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PASTEVENTS);

}
```

This is FetchLastDiagID 
 // Fetch Last Diagnosis ID created

```
   public HistoryTble FetchLastDiagnosisID()
{   
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Historytble + ""; 
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 

  if(db == null)
      return null;

  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
 HistoryTble  oHistryTble  = new HistoryTble();

try
{
  if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
  {
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
     do 
     { 
         oHistryTble.SetDiagnosisID(cursor.getString(1));

     } while(cursor.moveToNext());  
  }
  else
  {
      oHistryTble = null;
  }
}
finally
{

  if(db != null)
  {
      cursor.close();
      db.close();
  }
}
  return oHistryTble;

}
```

**This is my Crash Log**

```
       Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:779)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
at com.cdl.Database.DatabaseHandler.FetchLastDiagnosisID(DatabaseHandler.java:845)
at com.cdl.mircam.DiagCreation.GenerateDiagID(DiagCreation.java:1141)
at com.cdl.mircam.DiagCreation.onCreate(DiagCreation.java:249)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Unlikely to be due to the version difference. Please post the stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: I have add the crash log

Comment: Your methods seen in the stacktrace are `FetchLastDiagnosisID()`, `GenerateDiagID()` and so on - possibly the problem is there.

Comment: I have add FetchLastDiagnosis ID . Problem is not in this function. Same function work but after some time  same function it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Sqlite function call in NDK layer.

For every sqlite function call I was using

```
sqlite3_finalize(HRLY_stmt);

HRLY_Result = sqlite3_close_v2(HRLY_db);
```

But in one function I was closing database without finalize. This was causing problem for me after long run. And I was getting this exception on App layer(saying Unable to open database exception)

**Note:**  Make sure any database in  any condition is closing db only after finalize.

Same Issues was causing **TransactionTooLarge Exception** in long run on UI Tap

In Conclusion It resolved my two problem

1. Sqlite Unable to Open database exception seen in long run
2. TransactionToolarge exception seen  in long run